# Ubuntu on Windows running openAI gym, env.render() give out nothing

Tags: python, ubuntu, reinforcement-learning, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openai-gym

```
import gym

env = gym.make('Pong-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(10):
    env.render(mode='rgb_array')
    # I tried env.render(close = True) and env.render(close = False)
    env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action

# env = gym.wrappers.Monitor(env, 'results/carrace-1', force = True)
```

I ran this code on my Ubuntu on Windows, and the result only showed like

```
qrh@qrh:/mnt/d/RL$ python Pong.py
[2017-05-01 16:36:26,621] Making new env: Pong-v0
```

Nothing else.

Comment: we need more information, where did you get your set-up for ubuntu? Are you following instructions?

Comment: I just use the Bash on Ubuntu on Windows to make my environment. I follow the installing instruction on the website of Gym. Running           <git clone https://github.com/openai/gym>
<cd gym>
<pip install -e .[all] >

Comment: as a suggestion, open an issue on github.

Comment: Thanks! I have just opened one.

Comment: good to know :)